# Getting object or array value for Auth on Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm using angularfire 1.1.1 to store my apps objects and each object creates associated indexes. So when a user is created, that user is added to the 'users' table and then the users index table gets keyed with the UID and points to the actual user's id.

When the main state is called, I run a checkAuth() method to see if a user is signed in. If so, then I want to assign $rootScope.auth = {id:userID, role: role} etc.

The function works great in my login method but i don't know how to grab the value from my checkAuth() method. I've tried $value on both $firebaseObject and $firebaseArray, also tried to call them with [0] since there is only one id value in the table for each user's uid.

*The sloppy regex is for changing the semi-colon from SimpleLogin:47 to SimpleLogin-47 for keying to the index.*

Here's the code that doesn't work:

```
function authCheck(){
        var getAuth = $firebaseAuth(Data.ref);
        console.log('signed in as', getAuth.$getAuth().uid);
        var uid = getAuth.$getAuth().uid.toLowerCase().replace(/'+/g, '').replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');
        var userIndexRef = Data.ref.child('index/users/uid/'+uid);
        var userIndexArray = $firebaseArray(userIndexRef);
        var userIndexObject = $firebaseObject(userIndexRef);
        console.log(userIndexArray, userIndexObject);
        var realId = '';
        angular.forEach(userIndexObject, function(key, id){
            realId = id;
            $rootScope.auth = realId;
            return realId;
        });
    }
```

Here's the login code that does work:

```
function login(email, pass) {
        ref.authWithPassword({email:email,password:pass}, function(error, authData){
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('signed in as',authData.uid);
                var uid = authData.uid.toLowerCase().replace(/'+/g, '').replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "-").replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');
                angular.forEach(Data.dataObject.index.users.uid[uid],function(id, key){
                    $rootScope.role = Data.dataObject.users[id].role;
                    $rootScope.auth = {authData:authData, id:id, role:Data.dataObject.users[id].role};
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

If anyone sees where I've messed up, I'll be happy to know. Here's the repo https://github.com/irthos/medviz if it helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mods, please feel free to rewrite my question if it's at all misleading.

Comment: If you really insist on putting thing into $rootScope that belong in a service, what's wrong with just using `$firebaseAuth(Data.ref).$onAuth(function(authData) { $rootScope.authData = authData; })` as shown in [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-auth-state)?

Comment: Thanks @Kato. That works fine for logging in. My case is when a user is already logged in but refreshes the page whereupon a state is reloaded and so checks if auth is currently available

Comment: If you refresh the page, $onAuth() is still the correct answer. It's still going to require a trip to the server and it's still going to be updated with the current auth state when it gets done.